# how can i show Action bars in middle of the activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

i need suggestion to make the action bars in middle of the activity or anywhere in the activity same as the picture below

[image]

as i am trying with the fragments but could not figure it out how to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TabPagerIndicator control from the ViewPagerIndicator library

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Thanks rich for the suggestion, i just want to know weather i can use fragments to show action bars as in the image above or not.

Comment: There is only one ActionBar per screen, so don't think of those tab controls as an ActionBar

Comment: @VivekSingh yes, Look at the TabPagerIndicator sample code here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsDefault.java the tabs are populated with Fragments. And I think Rich is correct, those are not technically Action Bars, but they are styled to look like they are.